# How to make responsive Input from Semantic UI React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have Input component from Semantic UI React and I set its size for 100 vh. But I want to make it responsive so it would fit on the screen with lower resolution. I searched in this component's props on Semantic UI React site but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Use form group evenly divided https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#group-variations-evenly-divided-group

Comment: Usually i prefer using Grid style which I found really good to make web app responsive. In Semantic UI this is the link https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I tried to put Input inside these components but it didn't help

Comment: @Garry Yes, I use Grid and this is perfectly responsive, problem is with other components like Input or Menu Items, they are not responsive at all :(

Comment: You might wanna add screenshot or if you can explain me the situation, for me it is working like a charm

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/semantic-ui-react-example-fk1h5